# jQuery ajax response not operating correctly

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net, ajax

Ok this is frustrating... The code below works "correctly" as far as sending the email address to the SaveEmail URL and it gets saved correctly each time I change the drop down.  However it only outputs the "Successful" message once, no matter how many times I change the value in the drop down. The "data" that is returned is "Successful".  I would like to show the message for a couple seconds, then fade it out.  It works correctly the first time I change the drop down, after that the change happens and the value gets saved, but the "Successful" message doesn't display.

jQuery code:

```
$('#AgentEmails').change(function() {
  var NewAddress = $('#AgentEmails').val();
  $.post('SaveEmail.aspx', { email: NewAddress }, function(data) {
    $('#SelectMsg').html("<b>" + data + "</b>").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<select ID='AgentEmails' runat='server'>
  <option value="test@test.com">TEST</option>
</select><span id='SelectMsg'></span>
```

What needs to be changed in my code to make this operate correctly?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: NewAddress reaches the server successful every time?

Comment: Yes, I make many changes during testing and check the DB each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once fadeOut is executed, the display property of #selectMsg is set to none, so you won't see it again, unless you restore it's visibility.
For example:

```
$('#AgentEmails').change(function() {
  var NewAddress = $('#AgentEmails').val();
  $.post('SaveEmail.aspx', { email: NewAddress }, function(data) {
    $('#SelectMsg').show();
    $('#SelectMsg').html("<b>" + data + "</b>").fadeOut();
  });
})
```

Comment: nice focus on the actual issue and not side tracked by "what else" :)

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that could be chained into the original statement ahead of the ".html".

Answer (score 0):

the selection ain't made correctely
in asp.net there is a couple of different ways to make selection by jquery you shoudl try this code:

```
$("*[id$='AgentEmails']").change(function() {
  var NewAddress = $("*[id$='AgentEmails']").val();
  $.post('SaveEmail.aspx', { email: NewAddress }, function(data) {
    $("*[id$='SelectMsg']").html("<b>" + data + "</b>").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Comment: that makes no sense if what the OP says is true. Data is saved at all times so selection must be correct.

Comment: @jAndy: That wasn't me. I just indented the code so it was formatted correctly.

Comment: i used jquery in my previous projects, and i can't select with the commmon way, i've had to google a little to find some tricks,
but if he is using VS2010 the code above is useless.